# Show that $A/I \approx \mathbb{C}$ by using the isomorphism theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $I = R\cdot(x^2+1)$.

By constructing two isomorphisms, it is possible to show that $$A/I \approx \mathbb{C}.$$

I would like to do this same result using the isomorphism theorem, but I but I'm having trouble defining the function for that, I thought about taking the rest of the division by $x^2 + 1$, that have the form $ax+b$ and define the function as $\psi(p(x)) = a+bi$. But it is not working to prove that the kernel is the desired ideal.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can define a function $\phi: R \to \mathbb{C}$ by evaluating at $x = i$. That is, $p(x) \mapsto p(i)$.

Now suppose $\phi(p) = 0$. We can write $p = (x^2 + 1)q + (ax + b)$, for $q \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $p(i) = 0$, we must have $ai + b =  0$ so $a = b = 0$. Then $p = (x^2 + 1)q$. This shows $p \in (x^2 +1) \cdot R$ so that $\ker \phi \subseteq (x^2 + 1) \cdot R$.

However, the other inclusion is clear so that the kernel is the desired ideal. Also, $\phi$ is surjective by considering $\phi(ax + b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. By the 1st isomorphism theorem, you get that

$$ \mathbb{C} \cong R/(x^2 +1)$$

Comment: Thank you for your help.